# I keep getting this error - invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to call this function from a button, but keep getting invalid literal for int() with base 10: " ". I am a beginner and I could use some help. My goal is to multiple x and y together but it keeps giving me an error.

```
 # Estes Price
    estesPriceVal = Entry(main_window, width=50, borderwidth=5)
    estesPriceVal.grid(row=6, column=1)


    def calculateEstesPrice():
        X = int(estesPriceVal.get())
        Y = int(float(1.35))
        messagebox(X*Y)

Button(main_window, text="Calculate", bg="red", fg="white", command=calculateEstesPrice).grid(row=9, column=1
```

Comment: You are trying to convert a space to an int, which is not possible: `int(' ')`

Comment: why do ```Y = int(float(1.35))``` when you could just ```Y=1```? or just get rid of ```Y``` altogether

Comment: What does `estesPriceVal.get` do?

Comment: You would certain get this error if you clicked the button before you typed anything into the entry box.  In that case, `estesPriceVal.get()` will return an empty string, which will cause your error.  Perhaps you should check for that and put up an error.